# How to call ConfettiController from another class

Tags: flutter, dart

Inside MyAppState I have created a ConfettiController called controllerTopCenter that I got from this package - https://pub.dev/packages/confetti

I also added a key to MyApp in the hopes of triggering the confetti animation from another class.

In the other class I added `GlobalKey<MyAppState> key = GlobalKey<MyAppState>();` and then added `key.currentState.controllerTopCenter.play();` which will trigger every time a certain thing is achieved within the app. However when it is triggered I get the error message "NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'controllerTopCenter'".

I'm wondering what is causing this error.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:confetti/confetti.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  ConfettiController controllerTopCenter;

  void initState() {
    controllerTopCenter =
        ConfettiController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 10))
          ..addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    super.initState();
  }

  void dispose() {
    controllerTopCenter.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Tap tap = new Tap();

    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Sum Mini',
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: ConfettiWidget(
                  confettiController: controllerTopCenter,
                  blastDirectionality: BlastDirectionality
                      .explosive, // don't specify a direction, blast randomly
                  shouldLoop:
                      true, // start again as soon as the animation is finished
                  colors: const [
                    Colors.green,
                    Colors.blue,
                    Colors.pink,
                    Colors.orange,
                    Colors.purple
                  ], // manually specify the colors to be used
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  tap.onTap();
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.greenAccent,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Tap {
  GlobalKey<MyAppState> key = GlobalKey<MyAppState>();

  onTap() {
    key.currentState.controllerTopCenter.play();
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below
You can move `Tap tap` outside from `build` and pass to `MyApp` 
code snippet

```
Tap tap = new Tap();

void main() => runApp(MyApp(key: tap.key));
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:confetti/confetti.dart';

Tap tap = new Tap();

void main() => runApp(MyApp(key: tap.key));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  ConfettiController controllerTopCenter;

  void initState() {
    controllerTopCenter =
        ConfettiController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 10))
          ..addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    super.initState();
  }

  void dispose() {
    controllerTopCenter.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Sum Mini',
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: ConfettiWidget(
                  confettiController: controllerTopCenter,
                  blastDirectionality: BlastDirectionality
                      .explosive, // don't specify a direction, blast randomly
                  shouldLoop:
                      true, // start again as soon as the animation is finished
                  colors: const [
                    Colors.green,
                    Colors.blue,
                    Colors.pink,
                    Colors.orange,
                    Colors.purple
                  ], // manually specify the colors to be used
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  tap.onTap();
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.greenAccent,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Tap {
  GlobalKey<MyAppState> key = GlobalKey<MyAppState>();

  onTap() {
    key.currentState.controllerTopCenter.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, this did work with the condensed project I made up to explain my issue. However with my actual project when I implement this I get 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'controllerTopCenter' of null'. Do you have any idea how I can fix that or what the issue might be?

Comment: I can only fix with your reproduce code. if this is not work with your real project.. you need to revise your reproduce code to allow more people can help you.